# How to pull distance out of user text input in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a search bar visitors use to search for places nearby. It consists of two input boxes: keywords and distance.

I want to simplify it to one box, but allow visitors to enter a distance. They could enter terms like *"Costco within 5km"* or *"Denny's 2mi"*.

On the server side, I'd like to pull the distance out of that input. I realize there is a lot of room for error. The visitor could put a space after the number (4 km) or may use full text (4 kilometers), or probably any number of other issues to worry about.

If I wanted to offer the ability for visitors to enter (n)km, or (n)mi, what's a good way to parse the data into separate variables?

Let's say a visitor enters *"Chinese Indian Korean restaurants 5mi"*. I'd want to split it into:

```
string keywords = "Chinese Indian Korean restaurants";
string distance = 5; //(notice no mi, or km)
```

I'd imagine a regex of some sort would be required, but my regex skills are extremely lacking. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in this case Regular Expressions are your friend. I would focus on matching the distance and removing it from the input text. What remains is the keywords..

```
Regex distRex = new Regex("(?<dist>\\d+)\\s*(?<unit>mi|km|ft)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Then you could do this:

```
Match m = distRex.Match(testInput);
if(m.Success)
{
    string keywords = distRex.Replace(testInput, string.Empty);

    // you may want to further sanitize the keywords by replacing occurances of common wors
    //   like "and", "at", "within", "in", "is" etc.

    string distanceUnits = m.Groups["unit"].Value;
    int distance = Int32.Parse(m.Groups["dist"].Value);    
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Let me check this out in my code real quick. Looks like precisely what I needed.

Comment: Works almost precisely how I wanted, thank you! One issue... it doesn't seem to capture "5mi" but will capture "5km". Looks like the first unit after `<unit>` in this case mi, doesn't get picked up by the regex.

Comment: Never mind... found it was the code you had already updated (the ? inside of `<uni>`). Works perfect, thank you!